# Defining isomorphism classes in Coq

Tags: coq, isomorphism

How to define isomorphism classes in Coq?

Suppose I have a record ToyRec:

```
Record ToyRec {Labels : Set} := {
X:Set;
r:X->Labels
}.
```

And a definition of isomorphisms between two objects of type ToyRec, stating that two 
objects T1 and T2 are isomorphic if there exists a bijection f:T1.(X)->T2.(X) which preserves the label of mapped elements.

```
Definition Isomorphic{Labels:Set} (T1 T2 : @ToyRec Labels) : Prop :=
exists f:T1.(X)->T2.(X), (forall x1 x2:T1.(X), f x1 <> f x2) /\ 
                         (forall x2:T2.(X), exists x1:T1.(X), f x1 = f x2) /\
                         (forall x1:T1.(X) T1.(r) x1 = T2.(r) (f x1)).
```

Now I would like to define a function that takes an object T1 and returns a set 
containing all objects that are isomorphic to T1.

```
g(T1) = {T2 | Isomorphic T1 T2}
```

How one does such a thing in coq? I know that I might be reasoning too set theoretically 
here, but what would be the right type theoretic notion of isomorphism class? Or even more basically, how one would define a set (or type) of all elemenets satisfying a given property?

Comment: I don't know if you can do what you want: I don't see how you can constructively build this set, you would have to enumerate all possible functions or something in this flavor, and this seems impossible to me.

Comment: Injectivity should be `forall x y, f x = f y -> x = y` or `forall x y, x <> y -> f x <> f y`. Surjectivity should be `forall y, exists x, f x = y`. `forall x y : T, f x <> f y` is always false, unless `T` is empty. `forall y, exists x, f x = f y` is always true.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to do set theory in type theory. You should try working with predicates instead of sets.

Comment: In set theory, you usually take an equivalence relation and build an equivalence class, so you can rewrite with "standard" equality. In type theory, you usually just rewrite with the equivalence relation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It really depends on what you want to do with it. In Coq, there *is* a comprehension type `{x : T | P x}` which is the type of all elements `x` in type `T` that satisfy property `P`. However, it is a *type*, meaning that it is used to classify other terms, and not a *data-structure* you can compute with in the traditional sense. Thus, you can use it, for instance, to write a function on `T` that only works on elements that satisfy `P` (in which case the type of the function would be `{x : T | P x} -> Y`, where `Y` is its result type), but you can't use it to, say, write a function that computes how many elements of `T` satisfy `P`.

If you want to compute with this set, things become a bit more complicated. Let's suppose `P` is a decidable property so that things become a bit easier. If `T` is a finite type, then you can a set data-structure that has a comprehension operator (have a look at the [Ssreflect](http://ssr.msr-inria.inria.fr/~jenkins/current/Ssreflect.finset.html) library, for instance). However, this breaks when `T` is infinite, which is the case of your `ToyRec` type. As Vinz said, there's no generic way of constructively building this set as a data-structure.

Perhaps it would be easier to have a complete answer if you explained what you want to do with this type exactly.

Comment: Thanks. The library Ssreflect seems to have all I need. In my applications X is finite. Indeed, I just need to set X=\{1,...,n\} for n\in nat. Is there a nice notation to define this X? I couldn't find it in Ssreflect.

Comment: The fintype library of Ssreflect defines the `ordinal` type, which is essentially what you described. Have a look at http://ssr.msr-inria.inria.fr/~jenkins/current/Ssreflect.fintype.html. If `X` and `Labels` are always finite in your applications, then `{ T2 | Isomorphic T1 T2 }` is also finite; have a look at http://ssr.msr-inria.inria.fr/~jenkins/current/Ssreflect.finfun.html, the library of functions over finite domains.